# Transport data over two ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an app, where I have three hierarchical `tableViews`. The first one is a `tableView` with all the clubs of the user. When he selects a club he gets to the `ViewController`  , where all the members of the selected clubs are displayed.

In the code it looks like this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let destinationVC: UIViewController
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "memberViewController") as! MemberViewController
            destinationVC = vc
            let selectedRow = self.tableViewClub.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            
            vc.club = clubs[selectedRow!]
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
```

#### Problem

Then I can access the members of this club in the `MemberViewController`. And now I want to transfer the data again but this time to another `ViewController` which is connected to the `MemberViewController`with a `segue`.

#### Question

How can I transfer the members of the club to the `ViewController` - which is connected to the `MemberViewController` by a segue -  since there is no selected row I can write in the code.

Comment: you have the "club" property in your MemberViewController holding the data right ? pass the same to other VC what is the problem in this ?

Comment: You can pass data in prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) in MemberViewController. While Navigating to ViewController from MemberViewController this method will be called. Please refer [segue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your "MemberViewController", write this code :-

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
 // Create a new variable to store the instance of ViewController 
   if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController
    destinationVC.members = members
    }
}
```

This method gets called when you push one viewController to another via segue. So you can pass your "members" from "MemberViewController" to "ViewController"

Comment: Why this old version instead of prepare(segue:sender)?

Comment: Ohh yes, I was just telling you the idea. You can update the method.

Answer (score 0):

> You should give an identifier to segue and then try this code. in MemberViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "identifier"{
        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController
        dectination.clob = self.club
    }

}
```